# Delay or cancel (click) bind via Directive

Tags: angular, dom-events, angular-directive

I have many buttons like this one:

```
<button (click)="func()">Press me!</button>
```

I want to create a directive that will show confirm popup before executing `func()`. Like:

```
<button confirmModal (click)="func">Press me!</button>
```

That the logic of my confirm modal:

```
const confirmModal = this.modalService.open(ConfirmComponent);
confirmModal.result.then((result) => {
  if (result === 'confirm') {
    // execute func()
  }
}, (reason) => {});
```

But I have no luck to mix it together. Somehow need to make the directive that before executing `func()` will show popup. And based on result (true or false) will execute `func()` [(click) bind] or not. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[confirm]',
})
export class ConfirmDirective  {
  @Input() message: string;
  @Input() onConfirm: Function;
  @Input() onDismiss: Function;

  @HostListener('click') onClick(e: Event) {
     const confirmed = window.confirm(this.message);

     if (confirmed && this.onConfirm) {
       this.onConfirm();
     }

     if (!confirmed && this.onDismiss) {
       this.onDismiss();
     }
  }
}
```

Usage

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button confirm 
     [onConfirm]="onConfirm" 
     [onDismiss]="onDismiss" 
     [message]="'Are you sure?'">
       Click me
    </button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  onConfirm() {
    console.log('confirmed');
  }

  onDismiss() {
    console.log('dismissed');
  }
}
```

I've extended the directive to accept both, `onConfirm` and `onDismiss` callback functions, to make it a little bit more reusable. They are both optional.

Please not that  `[onConfirm]` accepts the reference to the callback function (`onConfirm` and not `onConfirm()`). The same applies to the `[onDismiss]`.

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yyxuhd)